# How to recover access to a lost YouTube app

Tags: google-cloud-platform, youtube-api

This is not really a code-related question but honestly I just don't know where else to get support from.

I'm working to this company that has many users authenticated through a YouTube App, they've lost access to the account that holds this app on Google Console.
The product is still partially working under that app, still uses same api key and secret but it's now having issues with rate limits.

Is there any way to recover/transfer this app to another account? Or at least point out WHICH email owns it? I could provide (to a verified Googler) some information to prove my best intentions, like API_KEY/SECRETS, some possible emails and/or domains associated with that account, whatever other info that might seem necessary.

Answer (score 1):

In order to verify project in question, I would suggest you to open a private issue report using this link [1] along with all related details (eg: project-number, project creation date etc.).

Best regards.

[1] - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187164&template=803901